# Is "integrate against" a proper verb+preposition combination?

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

One of my colleague keeps using "integrate against" as in the following sentence:

> The component A is integrated against the platform B.

Google search shows several hundreds of the form. As far as I know, however, "integrate" is typically used along with the preposition "with" or "into".

Could someone guide me on what is the correct usage? If "against" can be used, in what context is it proper?

Thank you.

Comment: You could ask your colleague where they picked up the usage. I can't finfd many examples outside the maths domain.

Comment: Is it supposed to mean that component A is integrated into platform B?

Comment: "Against" is valid in some uses in mathematics and related domains, but the term "integrate" there has a different meaning from the non-math term.

Comment: @Jim yes, it is.

Comment: @HotLicks: do you mean that "integrate against" can be used in terms of the integral? So, otherwise it must be an invalid usage. Is this correct?

Comment: I mean that "integrate", in the math sense, is essentially a different word from the common use of the term, so it is an error to assume that the same constructions can be used in either case.

Comment: @HotLicks In summary, "integrate against" can be used only in the mathematical sense and "integrate with/into" should be used for the other meanings or domains. Please confirm. (I'm asking this again because I haven't learned math in English and the use of "integrate against" in math domain is something I'm not familiar with either)

Comment: @Felipe1979  - There probably are a handful of non-math contexts where "against" could be deemed appropriate, but they are rare.

Answer (score 1):

In mathematics, to *integrate A against B* means *to perform the computation ∫ A* d*B* or, occasionally, *∫ A B*. In the usual English sense of the word *integrate* meaning *to combine objects A and B*, however, it is exclusively used with the prepositions *with* and *into* (see [here](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/integrate), for example). I think your colleague has heard *integrate against* in the mathematical usage and has mistakenly assumed it to share the usual English meaning.